# jsf messed up links

Tags: jsf, browser, controller, primefaces, hyperlink

I'm new to JSF. My application is working, but I'm confused with links in browser when using controller. BTW, there is also PrimeFaces in my app so don't be suprised with `p:` tags. Let's say I have 'list' and 'show' pages with controller doing redirection between them. First I'm on `http://localhost:8080/y/r/conversation/list.xhtml` page. There is link created with line `<p:commandLink action="#{lazyConversationBean.doShow(conv)}" ajax="false" value="View"/>`. lazyConversationBean acts here as my Controller. There is method:

```
public String doShow(Conversation c) {
    this.setSelectedConversation(c);
    return "view";
}
```

from which I got redirected to ...... again `http://localhost:8080/y/r/conversation/list.xhtml` (browser shows it) even when it's correct `http://localhost:8080/y/r/conversation/view.xhtml` page. There I have link `<p:commandButton action="#{lazyConversationBean.doList()}" ajax="false" value="Back to list"/>` and again controller has method:

```
public String doList() {
    return "list";
}
```

from which I got redirected to ... yeah, you guessed right ... `http://localhost:8080/y/r/conversation/view.xhtml` (that is again what browser shows) even when again it is correct `http://localhost:8080/y/r/conversation/list.xhtml` page.

It seams as browser link area is always one step behind page currently being displayed. I don't even know if it's some incorrect behaviour as I have no idea how to query google for this :D Just for test I did [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html) short tutorial, where netbeans created whole stack of code on one of my entities, and behaviour was the same, so it's not PrimeFaces magic related.

Can you tell my why it happens, and how to fix it? Users likes to copy correct links ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem, the framework is done like that. There are different methods to work around that. For example you can add create your actions like that :

```
public String doShow(Conversation c)
{
    this.setSelectedConversation(c);
    return "view" + "?faces-redirect=true";
}

<p:commandLink action="#{lazyConversationBean.doShow(conv)}" ajax="false" value="View"/>
```

It will force a redirect to the action view, so the URL in the browser will change.

EDIT : Here is the solution for faces-config.xml navigation (notice the `<redirect />`) :

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>outcome1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/outcome1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>outcome2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/outcome2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: I cannot do this. Deployment exception shows: `javax.el.ELException: Not a Valid Method Expression: #{lazyConversationBean.doShow(conv)}?faces-redirect=true`

Comment: and inside brackets its runtime exception: `javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{lazyConversationBean.doShow(conv)?faces-redirect=true}'

Comment: Great, it works. Is it possible, to make the same with faces-config.xml as it seams to be more elegant way.

Comment: You could have a look to PrettyFaces, does a great URL rewriting job. I've never tested, but many persons talks about it. For the faces-config, I've never tested that, you can give it a try but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Thanks again. This PrettyFaces looks very promising, as I planned to search how to create RESTful links.

Comment: @Mateusz the `faces-config` file comes from JSF 1.x where you had to put all your navigation rules (forward and redirect). Now in JSF 2.x you can return the name of the View you want to forward. From personal experience, it looks *elegant* (and even *simple*) when you have few pages to configure, not very good in a medium-large project.